# Gradle build failing - "A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:generateSafeArgsDebug' (type 'ArgumentsGenerationTask')."

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to open and run the android architecture components sample project here: https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/GithubBrowserSample in Android Studio. One one machine I'm able to get the project built and run just fine, but on my primary machine I'm seeing a build task error:

```
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:generateSafeArgsDebug' (type 'ArgumentsGenerationTask').
> No value has been specified for property 'enableGradleWorkers'.
```

I've tried the version of gradle and the gradle plugin that the project seems to have been built with, as well as the latest of each. I do have "android.enableGradleWorkers=true" specified in gradle.properties.

I haven't found this message when searching around, but I often see similar-looking errors when opening projects from different sources. I'd love to be able to fix this one, and ideally understand more about what to check when encountering build errors with projects from different sources in the future.